# plex grammar for describing 2 D objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, grammar, context-free-grammar

Is there any Plex structure generating library that can build and parse [Plex grammar](http://www.uow.edu.au/~markus/apods/doc/benchmark/TPbenchnode6.html), preferably in python?